# How do I remove items in my pandas groupby which only have one item associated with them?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe groupby with the following hierarchy:
Layer 1 - Group ID
Layer 2 - Sub-group ID
Layer 3 - Party account

I would like to remove any sub-group entries which only have 1 party account associated with them. Example below:

[image]

Ideally, the higlighted rows would be removed from my groupby because they only have one associated party account, whereas the rest have multiple.

Has anyone come across such a scenario before? It is important to maintain the group IDs. Example, the same sub-group ID may appear in other Group IDs, where it has another account. We cannot just remove all instances of where the sub-group ID == 1 in the source data.

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question. Should be easy to solve. But first, are you able to provide the sample data in text form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure how your data is stored, but it looks like at least the first 2 groups are probably levels of the index. In that case, it should actually be as simple as grouping by the first two levels and filtering for groups with more than 1 row:

```
df_filtered = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please clarify at what stage I apply this? The current output above is the result of the following: ```df.groupby(['Group ID','Sub-Group ID','Party account']).count()```

Comment: So probably something like `df.groupby(['Group ID','Sub-Group ID','Party account']).count().groupby(level=[0, 1]).filter(lambda g: len(g) > 1)`

Comment: @work_python did that solve your problem? :)

Comment: I will try tomorrow morning and report back’! Thanks a lot.

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much. I may have another updated question for you however...watch this space!